# Python: Sankey plot chart with complex data

Tags: python, sankey-diagram

I have the following dataset:

```
data = {
    '1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'NAN', 'A', 'C', 'NAN', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
    '2': ['B', 'NAN', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'NAN', 'A', 'C'],
    '3': ['NAN', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'NAN', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
    '4': ['C', 'B', 'NAN', 'A', 'B', 'NAN', 'C', 'A', 'NAN', 'B']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I want to perform a simple Sankey plot of this data structure. I dont even know where to start...

Comment: Sankeys can be a bit of a hell. Firstly, you need to have a clear understanding of what each property/flow represents. Here, the 1,2,3,4 does not reveal much. 
(You need to be careful with long vs wide formats also...)

*Plotly provides some very nice features for sankey diagrams.

Comment: thanks very much for the comment Thanos, indeed, it seems quite complicated. I guess the columns indicate the periods of transitions such as first period being 1, second period being 2 etc.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tricky to get the data in the correct shape.  Perhaps there is a more efficient way than what I have come up with, but hopefully this gets the job done.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    '1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'NAN', 'A', 'C', 'NAN', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
    '2': ['B', 'NAN', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'NAN', 'A', 'C'],
    '3': ['NAN', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'NAN', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
    '4': ['C', 'B', 'NAN', 'A', 'B', 'NAN', 'C', 'A', 'NAN', 'B']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.replace('NAN', np.nan)

# Get a list of labels by adding the column name to the the cell values and
# getting the discict combinations
label  = sorted(df.apply(lambda x: x+x.name).melt().dropna()['value'].unique())

# Iterate over two columns at a time to map out the relationships
output = []
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    output.extend(df[[str(i),str(i+1)]].value_counts().reset_index().apply(lambda x: x+x.name).values)

# Convert the relationships to the index of the labels list
mapped = []
for x in output:
    mapped.append((label.index(x[0]), label.index(x[1]), x[2]))

# Split the values into their corresponding buckets
source, target, value = np.array(mapped).T

# Build your chart
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
        label = label,
            color = "blue"
        
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = source,
        target = target,
        value = value
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Output

[image]